# How to upload CSV file as a post request in Karate 0.9.0 version?

Tags: karate

I am using Karate 0.9.0 version and I want to upload data using csv file. As per new update, it is converting data into JSON. But my API supports csv file format for upload function. How can I upload csv file in post request without converting data into json?

## Example

```
Given path 'xxx/upload'
And header Authorization = xxx
And header Content-Type = 'text/csv'
And request read('classpath:xxx.csv')
When method POST
Then status 202
```

P.S. This example was working in Karate version: 0.9.0.RC5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, that is indeed an edge case we hadn't thought of, but you have 2 options that will work nicely:

1) rename your CSV file to `*.txt`

```
And request read('classpath:xxx.txt')
```

2) use the karate.readAsString() API

```
And request karate.readAsString('classpath:xxx.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I don't want to convert  *.csv file in  *.text so second option is perfect for me and its working:)

Comment: @JimWright thanks for confirming ! I have actually updated the main README with these tips now, and also documented the `readAsString()` so others can find it